# Views tabs and argument

Tags: routes, views

I have a views with to page displays with following paths:

```
/question/%/popular (page, title - Popular)
/question/%/new (page_1, title - New)
```

The views has a contextual filter (argument) tid. I set the first page to be default tab (with parent menu item as Normal menu item in main menu), and the second one - a tab.

I expect at url /question/all to see a views display "page", with argument value "all", active Popular tab (with url /question/all) and also New tab (with url /question/all/new).

But I've got an error

```
Notice: Undefined index: localized_options in menu_navigation_links() (line 1861 of /var/www/notlookatme/data/www/qa.winfaq.info/includes/menu.inc).
```

And an item in main menu with url /question/%25

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be caused by a bug in Drupal 7: [Inaccessible menu items in navigation links cause "Notice: Undefined index: localized_options"](https://drupal.org/node/1018614). There is a patch available which has worked for some people.

Comment: confirmed: it worked for me!